# Finding all holomorphic function such $\text{Im} f(x+ i y) = e^x(x \sin y + \sin y+ y \cos y)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading a proof about finding all the holomorphic function such that $f(0) = 2$ and

$$\text{Im} f(x+ i y) = e^x(x \sin y + \sin y+ y \cos y)$$

But I can't understand two parts of it.

**Proof**

Calculating derivative $\text{Im} f(x+ i y)$ with respect to $y$:

$$v_y = e^x(x \cos y + \cos y + \cos y - y \sin y) = e^x(x \cos y + 2 \cos y - y \sin y)$$

Calculating derivative $\text{Im} f(x+ i y)$ with respect to $x$:

$$v_ x = e^x(x \sin y + \sin y + y \cos y) + e^x \sin y = e^x(x \sin y + 2 \sin y + y \cos y)$$

Calculating $u(x, y)$:

$$u(x, y) = \int v_y dx = \cos y e^x (x-1) + 2e^x \cos y - e^xy \sin y+ \alpha(y)$$

$$u(x, y) = -\int v_x dy = e^x(x \cos y + \cos y - y \sin y) + \beta(x)$$

Out of these facts we have that:

$$u(x, y) = e^x(x \cos y + \cos y - y \sin y) + C\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1) $$

Now because $u(0, 0) =0$ we have that $1 + C = 2 \Rightarrow C = 1$.

Finally our functions ($\phi(z) = u + iv$) are in form of:
$$\phi(z) = e^z(z + 1) + 1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (2)$$

**Questions**

I have two questions related to $(1)$ and $(2)$. I don't understand why out of two forms of $u(x, y)$ with $\alpha(y)$ and $\beta(x)$ we obtain form $(1)$ with some constant $C$.

Moreover, how out of form of $u(x, y)$ we are obtaining general form of all functions $\phi(z)$?

Comment: The two expressions read $u(x,y) = e^x(\ldots) + a(y)$ and $u(x,y) = e^x(\ldots) + b(x)$. So this is telling you that $a(y) = b(x)$. You can conclude from this what $a$ and $b$ has to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for you to have $(\forall x,y\in\Bbb R):\alpha(x)=\beta(y)$ is that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constant.

And if $u(x,y)=e^x(x\cos(y)+\cos(y)-y\sin(y))+1$ and $v(x,y)=e^x(x\sin(y)+\sin(y)+y\cos(y))$, then\begin{align}f(x+yi)&=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i\\&=e^x(x\cos(y)+\cos(y)-y\sin(y))+1+\bigl(e^x(x\sin(y)+\sin(y)+y\cos(y))\bigr)i\\&=e^x\bigl(x\cos(y)+\cos(y)-y\sin(y)+(x\sin(y)+\sin(y)+y\cos(y))i\bigr)+1\\&=e^x(\cos(y)+\sin(y)i)(x+1+yi)+1\\&=e^{x+yi}\bigl((x+yi)+1\bigr)+1.\end{align}